# Rename EFI Boot Partition "EFI Boot"

Tags: bootcamp, partition, startup, efi

I am trying to rename my Windows / Boot Camp partition from "EFI Boot" to "Boot Camp" or "Windows". But I do not figure out where to rename.

I tried `bless` command on the NTFS Volume, I tried creating the folders "System/Library/CoreServices" and copied the `.disklabel` file into it (or also `bless`it) but nothing changed.

Finally I got the Volume Icon on Boot Selection to work by copying the icns File onto the EFI partition. Also tried `bless`on the EFI partition – but this also do not work.

So I have my Icon, but I also would like to rename it – how can I do this?

Systems are Windows 10 and macOS Mojave.

Comment: In Windows Explorer, right-click on the drive, select rename. Does that not work?

Comment: I will test that but I don’t think so since the boot icon comes from the EFI partition. So I think the boot Name also comes from this partition. And i am pretty sure the name in windows is „Boot camp“ like in macOS. Only the boot screen shows „EFI boot“.

Comment: Perhaps you can rename it in Disk management (right click on Computer and select Manage > Disk Management)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking to create an entry in the Startup Manager menu where the entry has a custom icon and custom label. The image below shows this for Ubuntu. (For a better view, either click on the image or open image in a new window.) In your question, you have indicated you found how to create the custom icon, so I will not elaborate on this. You will find creating the custom label is a bit more difficult.

[image: 03]

First of all, the volume containing the `.VolumeIcons.icns` file should be `Mac OS Extended (Journaled)` formatted. The name of this volume will appear as the label on the Startup Manager menu. In this example the volume name is `Ubuntu`. The content of this volume is shown below. Basically this volume needs to be setup to appear as a legacy OS X boot volume.

> Note: Normally the `Ubuntu` volume would not appear in the Finder. In other words. the `/etc/fstab` file was edited so the `Ubuntu` volume would not auto-mount. I used the `diskutil` command to manually mount the volume. Also, the Finder windows does not normally show the hidden files.

[image: a1]

Some installations actually store the operating system boot files in volume. In this example, I instead chose to install rEFInd to silently boot Ubuntu. In other words, I added the following lines to the bottom of the default `refind.conf` file.

```
#
# Added to make rEFInd silent. 
#
menuentry "Ubuntu" {
    icon \System\Library\CoreServices\icons\os_ubuntu.png
    volume "EFI"
    loader \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
    ostype Linux
    graphics on
}
timeout -1
hideui all
scanfor manual
```

The actually Ubuntu boot files are stored in the hidden EFI partition, as shown in the image below.

> Note: The hidden EFI partition does not normally appear in the Finder and the Finder does not normally show hidden files.

[image: a2]

> Note: There is no `/EFI/BOOT` folder containing an `Bootx64.efi` file. This was done so a default icon labeled `EFI Boot` would not appear in the Startup Menu.

### What I do not understand is why you want to know how to do this with respect to Windows? Normally, the Startup Manager automatically inserts a `Windows` label for a properly installed Windows. There should be no need to apply the above procedure.